# Dask gridsearch giving error KeyError: 'finalize-c53697b4-1572-4d19-af41-c76b531699b9'

Tags: python-3.x, dask, xgboost, grid-search, dask-distributed

I am trying to do hyper parameter tuning for dask-xgboost but getting **KeyError: 'finalize-c53697b4-1572-4d19-af41-c76b531699b9'.**
Could anyone please help me out? I am unable to find any solution to this referring to the docs for dask-ml or dask-xgboost. The motive for trying to implement dask is using pandas and sklearn taking too long and kernel dies most of the time.

Below is the code snippet:

```
X_train_dask = dd.from_pandas(X_train, npartitions=10)
X_test_dask = dd.from_pandas(X_test, npartitions=10)
y_train_dask = dd.from_pandas(y_train, npartitions=10)

import dask
from dask.distributed import Client, progress        # task distribution

client = Client()
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators' : [500 , 750 , 1000],
    'max_depth': [15, 25 , 35  , -1],
    'colsample_bytree' : [ 0.7 , 0.9],
    'gamma' : [0.2 , 0.3 , 0.5],
    'subsample' : [ 0.7 , 0.8 , 0.9] ,
    'alpha' : [3, 4, 5],
    'learning_rate' : [0.05, 0.01, 0.008]
}
import dask_xgboost as dxgb
from dask_ml.model_selection import GridSearchCV as GSV
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold
clf = dxgb.XGBClassifier(random_state= 100,missing = -999) 
skf = GroupKFold(n_splits=3)
grid_search = GSV(clf, param_grid, scoring='roc_auc', refit=True ,
                           cv=skf, return_train_score=True)
grid_search.fit(X_train_dask.to_dask_array(), y_train_dask.to_dask_array()) 
print(grid_search.best_params_)
print(grid_search.best_score_ )
```

Below is the traceback:

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-3594cb1cb545> in <module>
      6 grid_search = GSV(clf, param_grid, scoring='roc_auc', refit=True ,
      7                            cv=skf, return_train_score=True)
----> 8 grid_search.fit(X_train_dask.to_dask_array(), y_train_dask.to_dask_array())
      9 print(grid_search.best_params_)
     10 print(grid_search.best_score_ )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_ml/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
   1255                     else:
   1256                         logger.warning("{} has failed... retrying".format(future.key))
-> 1257                         future.retry()
   1258                         ac.add(future)
   1259 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py in retry(self, **kwargs)
    308         Client.retry
    309         """
--> 310         return self.client.retry([self], **kwargs)
    311 
    312     def cancelled(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py in retry(self, futures, asynchronous)
   2058         futures: list of Futures
   2059         """
-> 2060         return self.sync(self._retry, futures, asynchronous=asynchronous)
   2061 
   2062     @gen.coroutine

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py in sync(self, func, asynchronous, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    751         else:
    752             return sync(
--> 753                 self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
    754             )
    755 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in sync(loop, func, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    326             e.wait(10)
    327     if error[0]:
--> 328         six.reraise(*error[0])
    329     else:
    330         return result[0]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in f()
    311             if callback_timeout is not None:
    312                 future = gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=callback_timeout), future)
--> 313             result[0] = yield future
    314         except Exception as exc:
    315             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
   1097 
   1098                     try:
-> 1099                         value = future.result()
   1100                     except Exception:
   1101                         self.had_exception = True

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _retry(self, futures)
   2047         response = await self.scheduler.retry(keys=keys, client=self.id)
   2048         for key in response:
-> 2049             st = self.futures[key]
   2050             st.retry()
   2051 

KeyError: 'finalize-c53697b4-1572-4d19-af41-c76b531699b9'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cluster is running out of memory

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
```

Please be aware that XGBoost needs all of the data to fit in RAM in order to train effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So is there any effective way to work with xgboost and large amount of data?

Comment: I think that there are some experimental efforts in XGBoost to allow for this, but in practice the answer is that you need to add more memory, either by using a larger machine, or by using more machines.